# Test local web service with Savon

Tags: ruby, soap, savon

I'm writing a gem to add support for SOAP services to Ruby (I hate myself for doing this but, you know, legacy systems are feeling lonely and gotta talk to someone), and I'm wondering if there's a way I can write some tests using Savon as a client library.

My question is: how can I tell Savon to call the WebService using `Rack::Test`?

The gem sources are hosted here: https://github.com/elementar/shapewear

Comment: get in touch via https://github.com/rubiii and we'll talk about it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up using the [WebMock](https://github.com/bblimke/webmock) gem. Here's the result:

https://github.com/elementar/shapewear/blob/master/spec/shapewear/savon_usage_spec.rb

```
describe Shapewear do
  describe "usage with SOAP clients" do
    before do
      stub_request(:get, "http://services.example.com/complete/soap/wsdl") \
        .to_return :body => CompleteService.to_wsdl, 
                   :headers => {'Content-Type' => 'application/xml'}

      stub_request(:post, "http://services.example.com/complete/soap") \
        .to_return :body => lambda { |r| CompleteService.serve(r) }, 
                   :headers => {'Content-Type' => 'application/xml'}
    end

    it "should work with Savon" do
      client = Savon::Client.new 'http://services.example.com/complete/soap/wsdl'
      response = client.request :echo_in_uppercase, :xmlns => 'http://services.example.com/v1' do
        soap.body = {:text => 'uppercase text'}
      end

      response.body[:echo_in_uppercase_response][:body].should == 'UPPERCASE TEXT'
    end
  end
end
```